# Why was question 58112290 removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, welcoming

I tried hard to understand the reasoning behind closing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112290/java-thread-thread-waiting-on-a-object-comes-out-of-wait-without-the-concerned/58112489#58112489). I couldn't get it, so I am asking for help here.

I'll post it here because some users might not see it.

> ### Java Thread - Thread waiting on a object comes out of wait without the concerned object notifies
>
> I have tried a Java program for inter-thread communication. Please
>   find the below program. This is the thread.
>
> ```
> public class Calculator extends Thread {
>   int total = 0;
>
>   public void run() {
>       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
>           total = total + i;
>       }
>       System.out.println("releasing the lock");
>   }   }
> ```
>
> Main program
>
> ```
> public class ThreadExample {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
>       calculator.start();
>       synchronized (calculator) {
>           try {
>               System.out.println("waiting for calculation to complete");
>               calculator.wait();
>           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           System.out.println(calculator.total);
>       }
>   }
> } The output is
> ```
>
> > waiting for calculation to complete
> >
> > releasing the lock
> >
> > 4950
>
> My doubt is, how the wait is completed without the calculator object
>   notifies?

It was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076490/wait-method-wakes-up-without-calling-notifynot-spurious-wakeup).

I rarely vote to delete a question. If I do, I follow this guidance.

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege.

It's not a very popular question and a slightly different search query may lead to no results.

Is it poorly written? No, it has a succinct example, the output of which is given, the problem is clear. The title can be improved.

Is it a word-for-word copy? Not really. They have little in common. Compare two snippets, which one is easier to read?

Please, note that I am not asking to undelete it, or to reopen it. If you find it justifiable and can clear it up for me, I'd be happy with the decision.

---

One more thing which I find even more disturbing (the reason I added `welcoming` here - it doesn't feel that way).

```
-63 21:11:54Z   removed     Java Thread - Thread waiting on a object comes out of wait without the concerned object notifies
-2  21:11:52Z   downvote    Java Thread - Thread waiting on a object comes out of wait without the concerned object notifies
```

It's clear that the downvote and the removal happened within a few seconds and were done by one person. What's the message? "Don't answer duplicates"? "Your answer sucks"? Why would one do that knowing they are going to delete it now anyway? It really upset me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect here.  Your question was closed by a gold badge holder as a duplicate, and then deleted by three other community members.  Apparently the community (or at least three members of it with significant reputation) did not consider it important enough to keep, as is their right.  In addition, you apparently got a decent answer to your question before it was deleted.  I'd say the outcome was pretty good.

Comment: You added the "welcoming" tag, because ___your___ answer got downvoted? Do you think you're still a new user?

Comment: _Don't answer duplicates_ is a fair message, though. We close questions because they shouldn't be answered. That's why closing makes people unable to answer them.

Comment: "...and were done by one person...Why would one do that knowing they are going to delete it now anyway? It really upset me." Seems like you're upset about an assumption you've made, rather than any objective fact.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Correction: it wasn't OP's  question, he was the one that provided the *"decent answer"*. But out of the 82 visitors on the question, three decided the answer wasn't decent after all. On the bright side, it only needs one more undelete vote.

Comment: @Tom is there any "welcoming" policy for "veterans"? I mean they also can be treated unfairly or/and unfriendly...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am the answerer. I am OK with having it closed (since the duplicate with a helpful answer was found), but I didn't expect it to be removed. I still believe it's a good question and might be "useful as search fodder".

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, as far as I know there isn't. In this situation I would create a new meta question asking if the `welcoming` tag could be used more broadly to applicable for any situation, not only new users. The tag description would need an update, too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you, guys, keep emphasising "the significant reputation" which isn't important when it comes to closing (you only need to have 10K+ reputation [which is a relatively low requirement] and common sense)

Comment: @ErikA It wasn't a duplicate when I added my answer. I didn't make any prior research (I know I should have). It was pretty specific and I doubted that I would find a dup (judging from the comments, people find it difficult as well). We also close questions because *no more answers are needed*. It doesn't mean answers to a dup are bad and should be downvoted (not my case)

Comment: That's meta nowadays, anyone coming here and daring to ask a question gets the welcome package.

Comment: I like your question,  don't understand why they deleted it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By voting to delete this question, I was suggesting the post and its answer add zero value to the site. I guess that wasn't obvious with only one duplicate, **so I added another 16 (4 in the duplicate label and 12 more in comments) to emphasize the point**. This question gets asked enough already.

I've submitted it for deletion again in the SOCVR room. **Edit**: But that submission was removed because SOCVR doesn't allow voting on posts being discussed on meta (oops, my bad).

I suggest again, here, that it should be deleted because I believe it provides zero value to the site.

Comment: FYI - I've binned your request in SOCVR - per our rules we do not allow requests for posts that are under active moderation/discussion on Meta. See [item 15 - subpoint #6](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-requests-youre-involved).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You really shouldn't search on StackOverflow, their engine is pretty bad. Use your favorite search engine instead and add `site:stackoverflow.com`, you'll get much better results.

Answer (score 11):

The question was closed as a duplicate of [wait method wakes up without calling notify(NOT SPURIOUS WAKEUP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076490/wait-method-wakes-up-without-calling-notifynot-spurious-wakeup) by a Java gold badge wielder, meaning it had been asked and answered before. Then it was deleted by three *other* users with a combined Java tag score of nearly *20,000*. That is a fairly strong indicator that the question served no additional value (e.g. from search or otherwise). It's also in direct contradiction of your claim that

> It's clear that the downvote and the removal happened within a few seconds and were done by one person.

As for whether the duplicate was valid, I can't say (as I haven't touched Java in at least 12 years). However, your answer seems to indicate the same thing as the answer on the target: that `this.notifyAll` is called once `this` process terminates. Whether `this` is `calculator`, `laurel`, or some other value seems irrelevant.

Comment: There's a stigma on deleting duplicates within a specific window.  No clear guidance exists on when it's OK to do that, and that seems to be what's happened here.  The closure and the deletion are two sides of the coin.  One user has been prominent and adamant about deleting those kinds of questions and it is of no surprise to me that they're back in the thick of it, deleting questions like this.

Comment: "I haven't touched Java in at least 12 years". Give it another 12 years :)

Comment: "with a combined Java tag score of nearly 20,000" - I don't see why the overall Java scope of the guys who closed it matters. You are basically saying "big guys came and deleted it, accept it" (no disrespect to anyone).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Or it means that their decision is as a bad as you try to make it here with your question.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko The intent there is to indicate that the community has clearly afforded them the position of "Java subject matter expert" -- e.g. users who are better positioned than anyone else to determine whether the post really differs from the duplicate. It is for this reason I referred to their Java tag score rather than their reputations (which would be even higher in general).